# How to show desktop background on second monitor when Windows is locked?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

When I lock my computer, the first monitor shows "Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to unlock", and the secondary monitor is just black. But in some office I saw the second monitor showing the desktop background.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you know what version of Windows the other computer was using?  Windows XP would show the desktop background when the computer was locked, so dual-screen backgrounds would show across both monitors.  However, this feature was removed in Windows 7 (and possibly Vista), and replaced with the "lock screen."  I couldn't find a way around this when I searched previously...

Comment: I don't know for sure, it can be or XP, or 7, most probably XP

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the ability to make the lock screen display the desktop background across both screens was removed in Windows 7.  The closest thing I can suggest for getting around this is to use a photo screensaver capable of displaying on both screens (the default Windows one doesn't do that).  You could even set it to use only one image for the "slideshow" if that's the only one you want it to display.  I have used [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) for this.  The screensaver option is not available in the free version (it's $25 for Pro) and really it's overkill just to solve this problem, but the program is nice and has some great features for getting the most out of your dualscreen setup.  You can even set it to display your current background as the lock screen (though it still only shows on the primary monitor).

Answer (score 0):

Try [WinLockPro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winlockpro/). The subtitle reads, "Windows 8 Screen Lock and Logon for Windows 7,Vista and XP".

Comment: unfortunately WinLockPro is abandonware. Last updated 2015. Could not run it on my win10