# Windows 8 Dual Screen Lock screen?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

I've come to notice that when I lock my computer, with my second monitor turned on, even though I have a dual screen wallpaper, the lock screen only shows the background on one of the screens, and the other the start menu colors.

Is it possible, either using a third party program or an inbuilt feature of windows 8, to allow the wallpaper to overflow onto the second screen when the lock screen is activated, just like desktop mode wallpapers (it spans across both screens).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure there might be third party software that does this but even XP did this.

Comment: @Ramhound I only had a single monitor when I was using XP, no never saw it.

Comment: Well telling you behavior you are getting now is normal.

Comment: @Ramhound , never said it wasn't normal - I'm asking if it's possible to span the image across both screens.

Comment: Sounds pretty close to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/427453/how-to-show-desktop-background-on-second-monitor-when-windows-is-locked

The short version is no, the lockscreen runs at a different security context than the desktop logged in user.